How to Use Python Hypothesis in Integration Tests
We've got pretty complex builder and factory classes/methods to build test/domain data for our unit tests using Hypothesis. Now for our integration tests, we'd like to use the same functionality, the only difference is that they should run only once regardless of the result of the test. One solution is to call example() on the composite strategy in the test (or test fixture) which works fine, but it prints a warning asking not to do it.
I also tried to force Hypothesis to run the test only once:
# This is for demo purposes, the actual factory class is much more complicated.
def foo(foo: int):
    print("calling foo")
    return foo


@given(st.builds(foo, st.integers()))
@settings(max_examples=1, phases=[Phase.generate])
def test_foo(x: int):
    print("running test_foo")
    assert False

But still runs it twice:
------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------
calling foo
running test_foo
calling foo
running test_foo

Now my question is:

Is it possible to get an example from a strategy without actually using @given?
If not, how can tell Hypothesis to run the test only one time?
Also why is it running the test twice anyway, where the max_example is one and there's no shrinking?

Thanks.



Is it possible to get an example from a strategy without actually using @given?


No, not really - a strategy is just a description of what choices the backend should make, and how to transform them, in order to create whatever you asked for.


If not, how can tell Hypothesis to run the test only one time?
Also why is it running the test twice anyway, where the max_example is one and there's no shrinking?


The the Hypothesis engine doesn't support this: the max_examples setting is the number of passing examples after which we'll stop, but we might execute some of your code before discovering e.g. an assume(False) which requires us to try again.
In your specific case, I think you're seeing one failing example, and then the final 'replay the minimal example' execution with all our reporting hooks in place.  In principle we could avoid that, but I don't think it's worth the code complexity given that shrinking is almost always enabled.

Here's what I recommend doing instead:
Provide explicit examples with the @example() decorator!  This allows you to precisely control the number of examples executed (by running only the explicit phase), determinism, etc.
You can then complement this by using Hypothesis' generation to find interesting examples if you wish, while keeping integration tests fast at other times.

Thanks for the details. I tried to use that but faced two issues; First, it expects @given() as well, which means the original issue is still there. Second, the @example() requires the exact test data, which defeats the purpose (i.e. I'd like to use the strategy to generate the data). Or am I missing something.
